# Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem - exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have a simple Powershell command that shows a list of shares and the ACL's on them.  I cannot get the CSV to not show: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem in the path column.  I read a lot of other posts here and I still can't seem to get this to work.  Here is my code:

```
get-childitem \\olympus\dfs\departments | get-acl  | select-object path,owner,group | export-csv “C:\security.csv”
```

My output shows:

Path
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\olympus\dfs\departments\Proformance

Please help.  I have tried a ton of different things and cannot get rid of this.  I just want folder names, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So create a property, use the PSPath property as a base, and take a substring that removes the first 38 characters (the *Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::* part).

```
get-childitem \\olympus\dfs\departments | get-acl  | select-object @{l="path";e={$_.PSPath.substring(38,$_.PSPath.Length-38)}},owner,group | export-csv “C:\security.csv”
```

Ok, so including things from the Access property complicates things because it's an array, so now basically you want each file to include several lines most likely, to list all of the users/groups that have access. This will iterate through the Access group for each file/folder's ACL. It only lists results that have access, but you can change that by removing the `|?{$_.AccessControlType -eq "Allow"}` portion, but honestly that's probably what you care about.

```
gci 'C:\Program Files' | get-acl  | %{$Acl=$_
    $_.Access|?{$_.AccessControlType -eq "Allow"}|Select -Unique IdentityReference|%{[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        "Path"=$ACL.PSPath.substring(38,$Acl.PSPath.Length-38)
        "Owner"=$ACL.Owner
        "Group"=$ACL.Group
        "Access"=$_.IdentityReference
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you results like:

```
Path                                                 Owner                                                Group                                                Access                                              
----                                                 -----                                                -----                                                ------                                              
C:\Program Files\7-Zip                               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                         
C:\Program Files\7-Zip                               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                 
C:\Program Files\7-Zip                               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  BUILTIN\Administrators                              
C:\Program Files\7-Zip                               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  BUILTIN\Users                                       
C:\Program Files\7-Zip                               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  CREATOR OWNER                                       
C:\Program Files\Application Verifier (x64)          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                         
C:\Program Files\Application Verifier (x64)          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Comment: Ok, that worked perfectly!  One last question though.  when I add the select-object accessstostring, I get the output:

OLYMPUS\Internal_audit Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize

what is I just want the group that has access to the share, not the attributes: ReadandExecute, Write etc...

Comment: Ok, you just complicated things. You are now taking an array of objects, and including a property for each object that is itself an array, so you have an array of arrays. Give me a minute and I'll get you something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which uses the `Select-Object` command to create a "calculated property."

```
get-childitem \\olympus\dfs\departments | get-acl  | select-object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = { ($_.PSPath -split '::')[1] }; };,owner,group | export-csv "c:\security.csv";
```

Here's a working sample, that should work on any typical, clean Windows computer:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\Program Files' | Get-Acl | Select-Object -Property @{ Name = 'Path'; Expression = { (.PSPath -split '::')[1]; } },Owner,Group;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to remove the PowerShell path to achieve the result you expect. Here's an example that uses a custom header (object) with the Convert-Path cmdlet, which converts a Windows PowerShell path to a Windows PowerShell provider path; in this case, the FileSystem provider with a more concise name.

Get-ChildItem \olympus\dfs\departments | Get-Acl | Select-Object @{n="Path"; e={Convert-Path $_.Path}},owner,group

Comment: While this may be correct, your answer should include more than just code.  Please see [Answer] for more information.